# How to get the labels from tensorflow dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
ds_test = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    file_pattern = "./dfj_test/part-*.csv.gz",
    batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=1, 
    #column_names=use_cols, 
    label_name='label_id',
    #select_columns= select_cols,
    num_parallel_reads=30, compression_type='GZIP',
    shuffle_buffer_size=12800)
```

This is my tesetset during training. After completing the model, I want to zip the columns of predictions and labels for the `df_test` .

```
preds = model.predict(df_test)
```

Getting the predictions is quite simple, and it is of numpy array format. However, I don't know how to get the corresponding labels from the df_test.
I want to zip(preds, labels) for further analysis.
Any hint? Thanks.

(tf version 2.3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map each example to return the field you want

```py
# load some exemplary data
TRAIN_DATA_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv"
train_file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("train.csv", TRAIN_DATA_URL)
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(train_file_path, batch_size=100, num_epochs=1)
```

```py
# get field by unbatching 
labels_iterator= dataset.unbatch().map(lambda x: x['survived']).as_numpy_iterator()
labels = np.array(list(labels_iterator))
```

```py
# get field by concatenating batches
labels_iterator= dataset.map(lambda x: x['survived']).as_numpy_iterator()
labels = np.concatenate(list(labels_iterator))
```

Comment: The unbatch() option works. Thanks. By the way, do u know any method of counting all the samples of the dataset in an efficient way ?

Comment: for num, _ in enumerate(ds_train): 
    pass.